# How to make the lines touch the corner of my container class?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to make simple variation of Japanese imperial flag using @keyframes, some red lines are touching the container while other's don't. Can't figure it out...

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.red-dot {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: 1s expand ease-out forwards;
}

.line-1 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
}

.line-2 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.line-3 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.line-4 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
}

.line-5 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.line-6 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(225deg);
}

.line-7 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(270deg);
}

.line-8 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(315deg);
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
  }
}

/* .red-dot:hover .line {
    animation-name: expand;
  } */
```

Also when i decrease the height every line except 1 could not touch the corner, will be great if you will give any advice how to correct it

Comment: Please include relevant html and if possible make a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `height: 100%` inside `@keyframe` will end up reaching `parent's` height (i.e., `.container` class's size).
So better let it expand outside the `.container` and add `overflow:hidden` to hide the leakage.

You haven't shared any HTML, but from the code, this is what I could make up.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #fcc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red-dot {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  height: 0;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: 1s expand ease-out forwards;
}

.line-1 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
}

.line-2 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.line-3 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.line-4 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
}

.line-5 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.line-6 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(225deg);
}

.line-7 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(270deg);
}

.line-8 {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(315deg);
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 200%;
  }
}

.red-dot:hover .line {
  animation-name: expand;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red-dot">
    <div class="line line-1"></div>
    <div class="line line-2"></div>
    <div class="line line-3"></div>
    <div class="line line-4"></div>
    <div class="line line-5"></div>
    <div class="line line-6"></div>
    <div class="line line-7"></div>
    <div class="line line-8"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```